# sshpass unexpected token -p error for case inside bash

Tags: linux, bash, syntax-error, case

I am getting syntax error when trying to use sshpass as shown below.

```
case $var in
        1)
            echo "connecting: SERVER1" ;;
            sshpass -p "SomePassw0rd" ssh user123@some.ip.1 ;;
        2)
            echo "connecting: SERVER2" ;;
            sshpass -p "SomePassw0rd123" ssh user123@some.ip.2 ;;
esac
```

Eroor:

```
./test1: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `-p
./test1: line 11: sshpass -p "SomePassw0rd" ssh user123@some.ip.1
```

Could you please guide how ot fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Paste your script at https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fixes the  reported issues.
Remove the extraneous `;;` after the `echo` lines

Comment: `;;` should only occur once after all your commands in each case options.

Comment: Not sure where my past comments went. But thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case $var in
        1)
            echo "connecting: SERVER1"
            sshpass -p "SomePassw0rd" ssh user123@some.ip.1
            ;;
        2)
            echo "connecting: SERVER2"
            sshpass -p "SomePassw0rd123" ssh user123@some.ip.2
            ;;
esac
```

You may also want to consider using sshpass -f passwordfile.txt in order to avoid security issues related to having a password on the command line.